# C++ - Count integers from .txt file

Tags: c++

I want to count integers from *.txt* file named "Example.**in**", which contains (for example):

```
1  2  3  4  5
3 6 7
5 8
8 9 10 11
```

**1.** and returns me a 11, in this case (Integers that repeat counts as 1 - unique number count only). At this point, it only prints out 0 (I think there's problem with opening file at this stage).

**2.** prints out only the first integers in every row - 1, 3, 5, 8.

```
 int integer_count(){
 int count = 0;
 int i;
 ifstream fin;
 fin.open("Example.in"); //.txt file

 while(fin >> i)
 {
     count++;
 }
fin.close();
return count; // In this case it should print 14 instead of 11, 
    because I didn't count out 3, 5 and 8 (which duplicates - haven't figured         
    out  how to make unique count that would close eye for duplicates and 
    just count unique integers.)
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger, to see what it, actually, reads?

Comment: You can try inserting the element you read in a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) that is a container that store unique elements following a specific order. Then you read the size of the set.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm kinda new to this stuff. I checked twice, but didn't see anything that stands out. Program outputs - 0, which is starting state of total, which means, it didn't probably even open file, but - why?

Comment: @JasonM What do you mean by _I checked twice_? Did you run your code under a debugger, and stepped through it, step by step? Since then, you could see where the program's behavior starts to differ from your expectations.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Well, not sure if I've enough knowledge on debuggers, but I set the starting point at the beginning of function and runned through every line and I found : Cannot open file: ../../../../../src/gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c
Why is it acting like that and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @JasonM If you don't have enough information about debuggers, there is enough information about them, on the internet. You just have to do some research. I don't have enough information about the environment that you are using (and, steps taken, to get that error, are unclear/not specific enough), to be able, to give you a definite answer on the error.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'll surely read on debuggers. Also, I'm using codeblocks. When I change filename to "Example.in.txt" it works, but why it gives me a hard time when I have "Example.in" with out .txt at the end? Weird.

Comment: The comment beginning on the line with `return count;` should be `/*` type.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the file, you should always check whether or not the opening process has succeed. I believe that `file_name.good()` is a perfect boolean function to do that. Just make a simple if statement to see if it works, like that:

```
 if(fin.good()) std::cout << "File opened!";
 else{ //do something when opening didn't work }
```

Additioanlly, I believe you also need to write the 'full file name', which in this case (if your file name is exactly "Example.in") would be "Example.in.txt".

For the unique integers problem, there are couple solutions: either make a `std::vector` that stores already read integers from file and everytime you try to read another one, check whether or not it was already read (fastest algorithm here would be quick/heap/merge sort + binary search, instead of iterating everytime). Always when new integer is added, increase your `count` value by one.

Second solution is: just store your integers in vector and get rid of the multiples by iterating and erasing. Then `count` would just be `your_vector.size()`.

"Printing each integer that starts a new line" is a diffrent problem. I would switch from using `while(fin >> i)` to `getline()` function. That way, I have each line of file as a string, that can be turned into row of integers. With your `while()` loop, you do not know when the new line stars, so it's impossible to complete second task (or, after the task 1, you could open a file once again and use another algoritm only for getting the first integers of every line)

Last thing: As many people here stated, using a debugger is highly recommended. It saved me hours of pondering what is wrong, by just simply going through code, line by line. Codeblocks offers a really good debugger, so I encourage you to simply google a codeblocks debugger guide. Even YouTube has some tutorials covering that.